# Using QGIS in medical Science?

Tags: qgis, raster, image

I was wondering if anybody would be interested in collaborating?

My Idea is using QGIS to analyze and quantify Immunofluorescence raster images of cells from human serum.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't fit within this scope of questions allowed on this site.

Comment: Benjamin - think you'll be closed! I think you could be onto something with your proposal, but you really need to have a think about couching it as a question ... have a look at the current crop of raster capabilities in most GIS packages.

Comment: It is not possible for others to send you a message since your mail adress in your profile is not visible to the public.

Comment: Perhaps post this as a _Community Question_, similar to [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128164/using-gis-tools-for-non-geographical-problems)?